# R Change bar order grouped box-plot (fill-variable)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

edit: I rewrote the whole post including an example that is possible to replicate directly, and also containing the solution provided by Paweł Chabros. Thank you Paweł Chabros for providing a very neat answer!

In the following picture I struggle reversing the order of the box-plots, wanting to change it to go from October to December when looking left to right:

[Click here to display plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRNZR.png)

The dataframe is created by

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

name <- c('A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 
          'B','B','B', 'B','B','B', 'B','B','B',
          'C','C','C', 'C','C','C', 'C','C','C')
month = c("oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018",
         "oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018" ,
         "oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018" )
value <- seq(1:length(month))

df = data.frame(name, month, value)
df
```

The data frame looks like this

```
name    month   value
A   oct 2018    1
A   oct 2018    2
A   oct 2018    3
A   nov 2018    4
A   nov 2018    5
A   nov 2018    6
A   dec 2018    7
A   dec 2018    8
A   dec 2018    9
B   oct 2018    10
B   oct 2018    11
B   oct 2018    12
B   nov 2018    13
B   nov 2018    14
B   nov 2018    15
B   dec 2018    16
B   dec 2018    17
B   dec 2018    18
C   oct 2018    19
C   oct 2018    20
C   oct 2018    21
C   nov 2018    22
C   nov 2018    23
C   nov 2018    24
C   dec 2018    25
C   dec 2018    26
C   dec 2018    27
```

The plot in the figure above is created by

```
wantedMonths = c("oct 2018", "nov 2018", "dec 2018")
wantedNames = c("A", "B")
df2= df[df$name %in% wantedNames, ] 
ggplot(df2[df2$month %in% wantedMonths , ])  +  geom_boxplot(aes(as.factor(name), value, fill=month))#fct_rev(month)
```

The command that creates the correct plot, which was provided by Paweł Chabros, is

```
ggplot(df2[df2$month %in% wantedMonths , ])  +  geom_boxplot(aes(as.factor(name), value, fill=fct_rev(month)))
```

Comment: Try to wrap  `var3` with this function: `forcats::fct_rev()`.

Comment: Could you add sample data using `dput(head(df,15))`? Also could you explain what your code is attempting to achieve? `ggplot(df2[df2$var3 %in% wantedVar1s , ])`

Comment: Pawel Chabros: That worked! I re-wrote the whole post, including your answer. Thanks!

Comment: NelsonGon: I re-wrote the whole post. It should now be more understandable. Also it now includes a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot uses the order of the factor for this purpose. You can set month as ordered factor either inside ggplot call or change it before, in the data. In that case just add the following line before ggplot call:

```
df[['month']] = ordered(df[['month']], levels = c('oct 2018', 'nov 2018', 'dec 2018'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the ordering of the bar you can set them manually by `scale_colour_manual` function.
Just add the this while plotting with ggplot.
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","green","blue"))

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more detail(including code). Otherwise, this is better left as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, which is also included in the edited question, is to use fct_rev:

```
ggplot(df2[df2$month %in% wantedMonths , ])  +  geom_boxplot(aes(as.factor(name), value, fill=fct_rev(month)))
```